# Concatenating __DIR__ constant with a string as an array value which is a class member in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, string, class, constants

Can anyone tell me why this doesn't work?
It's just a crude example of what I'm trying to do somewhere else.

```
$stuff = array(
    'key' => __DIR__ . 'value'
);
```

However, this produces an error:

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '.', expecting ')' in /var/www/.../testing.php on line 6
```

Also, this works:

```
$stuff = array(
    'key' => "{__DIR__} value"
);
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response ManseUK.
In the interest of understanding my problem a little more - what does it return?
I var_dump'ed it:
string(26) "/var/www/../trunk"

Comment: set $stuff value on your constructor

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The first piece of code does not work because it's not a constant expression, as you are trying to concatenate two strings.  Initial class members must be constant.

From the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/language.oop5.properties.php):

> [property] initialization must be a constant value--that is, it must be able to be evaluated at compile time and must not depend on run-time information in order to be evaluated.

Comment: So because __ DIR __ is the current file's location its runtime information so isn't available at compile time.
Thanks Tim.

Comment: @acairns:  Not exactly.  PHP has the value of `__DIR__` when the script is being compiled, as you can see when initialising the string like: `"{__DIR__} value"`.  How you're accessing the magic constant is the only difference here, where one is seen as a constant expression and the other is not.

Answer (score 3):

You can't use operator in a property initialization. The workaround is to use the constructor:

```
public function __construct()
{
  $this->stuff = array(
        'key'   =>  __DIR__ . 'value'
  );
}
```

From the PHP doc:

> This declaration may include an initialization, but this
>   initialization must be a constant value--that is, it must be able to
>   be evaluated at compile time and must not depend on run-time
>   information in order to be evaluated.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php

Answer (score 0):

Set $stuff value on your constructor

```
function __construct()
{
$this->$stuff = array(
        'key'   =>  __DIR__ . 'value'
    );
}
```